# Stop adopting [orphan]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

The tag [orphan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orphan) "Orphan refers to code or data which exists outside of its intended context." seems rather ambiguous, but I'm not sure what to do with it. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with some of the uses of "orphan", so I can't make a recommendation.

There's also the tag [orphaned-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orphaned-objects) "one that cannot be found in the directory tree. File system objects can become orphaned when the directories that referenced them are damaged.", and [all-delete-orphan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/all-delete-orphan).

[Hibernate deleting orphans when updating collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304862/hibernate-deleting-orphans-when-updating-collection) talks about deleting orphans in Hibernate, while [Html Conditional PageBreak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16456703/html-conditional-pagebreak) is talking about orphan text in HTML/CSS.

Should we be creating new tags, fixing the tag wiki for "orphan", retagging some cases of "orphans" to related tags, or just burninating?

Comment: Throw it out into the streets and let it starve.  It would make a Grimm Christmas fairy tale:)  Lets get rid of it.